# Countdown timer - the days to hours

Tags: javascript, countdown

I used countdown timer from this site: http://www.littlewebthings.com/2010/02/jquery-countdown-script/

how would I show the days to hours? Type: 2 days 48 hours show. – 3 days 72 hours show ..

Heres the js code.

```
/*gpl stuff*/
(function($){

    $.fn.countDown = function (options) {

        config = {};

        $.extend(config, options);

        diffSecs = this.setCountDown(config);

        if (config.onComplete)
        {
            $.data($(this)[0], 'callback', config.onComplete);
        }
        if (config.omitWeeks)
        {
            $.data($(this)[0], 'omitWeeks', config.omitWeeks);
        }

        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .digit').html('<div class="top"></div><div class="bottom"></div>');
        $(this).doCountDown($(this).attr('id'), diffSecs, 500);

        return this;

    };

    $.fn.stopCountDown = function () {
        clearTimeout($.data(this[0], 'timer'));
    };

    $.fn.startCountDown = function () {
        this.doCountDown($(this).attr('id'),$.data(this[0], 'diffSecs'), 500);
    };

    $.fn.setCountDown = function (options) {
        var targetTime = new Date();

        if (options.targetDate)
        {
            targetTime = new Date(options.targetDate.month + '/' + options.targetDate.day + '/' + options.targetDate.year + ' ' + options.targetDate.hour + ':' + options.targetDate.min + ':' + options.targetDate.sec + (options.targetDate.utc ? ' UTC' : ''));
        }
        else if (options.targetOffset)
        {
            targetTime.setFullYear(options.targetOffset.year + targetTime.getFullYear());
            targetTime.setMonth(options.targetOffset.month + targetTime.getMonth());
            targetTime.setDate(options.targetOffset.day + targetTime.getDate());
            targetTime.setHours(options.targetOffset.hour + targetTime.getHours());
            targetTime.setMinutes(options.targetOffset.min + targetTime.getMinutes());
            targetTime.setSeconds(options.targetOffset.sec + targetTime.getSeconds());
        }

        var nowTime = new Date();

        diffSecs = Math.floor((targetTime.valueOf()-nowTime.valueOf())/1000);

        $.data(this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);

        return diffSecs;
    };

    $.fn.doCountDown = function (id, diffSecs, duration) {
        $this = $('#' + id);
        if (diffSecs <= 0)
        {
            diffSecs = 0;
            if ($.data($this[0], 'timer'))
            {
                clearTimeout($.data($this[0], 'timer'));
            }
        }

        secs = diffSecs % 60;
        mins = Math.floor(diffSecs/60)%60;
        hours = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60)%24;
        if ($.data($this[0], 'omitWeeks') == true)
        {
            days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24);
            weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
        }
        else 
        {
            days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24)%7;
            weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
        }

        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'seconds_dash', secs, duration ? duration : 800);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'minutes_dash', mins, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'hours_dash', hours, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'days_dash', days, duration ? duration : 1200);
        $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'weeks_dash', weeks, duration ? duration : 1200);

        $.data($this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);
        if (diffSecs > 0)
        {
            e = $this;
            t = setTimeout(function() { e.doCountDown(id, diffSecs-1) } , 1000);
            $.data(e[0], 'timer', t);
        } 
        else if (cb = $.data($this[0], 'callback')) 
        {
            $.data($this[0], 'callback')();
        }

    };

    $.fn.dashChangeTo = function(id, dash, n, duration) {
          $this = $('#' + id);

          for (var i=($this.find('.' + dash + ' .digit').length-1); i>=0; i--)
          {
                var d = n%10;
                n = (n - d) / 10;
                $this.digitChangeTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + ' .' + dash + ' .digit:eq('+i+')', d, duration);
          }
    };

    $.fn.digitChangeTo = function (digit, n, duration) {
        if (!duration)
        {
            duration = 800;
        }
        if ($(digit + ' div.top').html() != n + '')
        {

            $(digit + ' div.top').css({'display': 'none'});
            $(digit + ' div.top').html((n ? n : '0')).slideDown(duration);

            $(digit + ' div.bottom').animate({'height': ''}, duration, function() {
                $(digit + ' div.bottom').html($(digit + ' div.top').html());
                $(digit + ' div.bottom').css({'display': 'block', 'height': ''});
                $(digit + ' div.top').hide().slideUp(10);


            });
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What are you asking for? Do you want to show the countdown in hours only? As in, never show the weeks or days counters that their demos show?

Comment: hi patrick - yes. I want only hours minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide those you don't want in HTML code. as simple as that.

```
<div id="countdown_dashboard">



        <div class="dash minutes_dash">
            <span class="dash_title"></span>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
        </div>

        <div class="dash seconds_dash">
            <span class="dash_title"></span>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```